# ADO record sets start making new connections after 16 creations

Tags: vb.net, teradata, ado

This is probably the most confused with a bug I've ever been.

Here's some VB code which will produce the error. I'm not interested in the fact I don't have to be creating new recordSets, this is intentional to trigger the bug.

```
Public Module ConnectionSetup

Public ActiveTDConnection As ADODB.Connection

Public Sub ConnectToTD(ByVal userName As String, ByVal Password As String, ByVal dsn As String)

    ActiveTDConnection = New ADODB.Connection

    ActiveTDConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=True;" & _

              "User ID=" & userName & ";Password=" & Password & ";" & _

              "Data Source=" & dsn & ";Mode=Read;" & _

              "UID=" & userName & ";AUTHENTICATION=LDAP;Initial Catalog=(Default)"

    ActiveTDConnection.CommandTimeout = 0

    ActiveTDConnection.Open(ActiveTDConnection.ConnectionString)

End Sub

End Module

Module Module1

 Sub Main()

    ConnectionSetup.ConnectToTD("XXX", "XXX", "XXX")


    Dim DB_qry As String

    Dim sessionQry As String

    Dim i As Integer = 1

    Dim sessionRS As New ADODB.Recordset


    DB_qry = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbc.databases"

    sessionQry = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbc.SessionInfo WHERE userName = 'MyUserName'"


    Do While i <= 18

        Dim DB_rs As New ADODB.Recordset

        DB_rs.Open(DB_qry, ActiveTDConnection)

        sessionRS.Open(sessionQry, ActiveTDConnection)

        ' This starts going up by 1 on each loop, after 16.
        Debug.Print(sessionRS.Fields.Item(0).Value)

        Do While Not DB_rs.EOF

            MsgBox(i)

            i += 1

            DB_rs.MoveNext()

        Loop

        DB_rs.Close()

        DB_rs = Nothing

        sessionRS.Close()

     Loop

 End Sub
```

After the 16th iteration, each newly opened recordSet spawns a new connection. So my code randomly starts risking maxing out the session limit.

1.) Why is this happening?

2.) How can I prevent it?

Comment: Not experiencing your error. Can you try removing references to sessionRS - id est - open a single recordSet at a time inside a connection (DB_rs)? What is your TD client version?

Comment: I know it's a dumb way to write it, but it's the simplest case that would trigger the issue on my end. I'm using 14.10.05.10

Comment: Could you run it as: DB_qry = "SELECT SESSION" - and instead of MsgBox(i) - output - MsgBox( DB_qry.Fields.Item(0).Value ) - to see if you are actually using different connections ?

Comment: I'm sorry to ask for "code it for me", but I'm not following

Comment: See the example in the answer (which allows code formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Sub Main()

    ConnectionSetup.ConnectToTD("XXX", "XXX", "XXX")


    Dim DB_qry As String
    Dim sessionQry As String

    Dim i As Integer = 1

    Dim sessionRS As New ADODB.Recordset

    DB_qry = "SELECT SESSION"

    sessionQry = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbc.SessionInfo WHERE userName = 'MyUserName'"


    Do While i <= 18

        Dim DB_rs As New ADODB.Recordset

        DB_rs.Open(DB_qry, ActiveTDConnection)

        sessionRS.Open(sessionQry, ActiveTDConnection)

        ' This starts going up by 1 on each loop, after 16.
        'Debug.Print(sessionRS.Fields.Item(0).Value)

        Do While Not DB_rs.EOF

            MsgBox("Sessions: " & sessionRS.Fields.Item(0).Value & " Cnt: " & i & " SID: " & DB_rs.Fields.Item(0).Value)

            i += 1

            DB_rs.MoveNext()

        Loop

        DB_rs.Close()
        DB_rs = Nothing
        sessionRS.Close()

     Loop

 End Sub
```